# Varnish: Syslog showing error aid *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/varnishd terminated

Tags: varnish

I am getting error from the sys log. and running on 8 Core 8G cloud server.

varnish running with following configuration:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
             -p thread_pools=8 \
             -p thread_pool_min=400 \
             -p thread_pool_max=6000 \
             -p session_linger=50 \
             -p sess_workspace=524288 \
             -s malloc,6G"
```

Not sure what is wrong here, and traffic to the server is ~ 1500/sec

```
--
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/varnishd terminated
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said ======= Backtrace: =========
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f8d7e8b2f47]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109e40)[0x7f8d7e8b1e40]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /usr/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_cookie.so(vmod_set+0x128)[0x7f8d74ae9548]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /usr/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_cookie.so(vmod_parse+0x1b1)[0x7f8d74ae97b1]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said ./vcl.Q3hwTxz8.so(+0x2afc)[0x7f8d74efaafc]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /usr/sbin/varnishd(VCL_recv_method+0x48)[0x438458]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /usr/sbin/varnishd(CNT_Session+0xf2b)[0x41982b]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /usr/sbin/varnishd[0x4333b5]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f8d7eb6fe9a]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f8d7e89c3fd]
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said ======= Memory map: ========
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 00400000-0047d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 412748                             /usr/sbin/varnishd
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 0067c000-0067d000 r--p 0007c000 ca:01 412748                             /usr/sbin/varnishd
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 0067d000-00680000 rw-p 0007d000 ca:01 412748                             /usr/sbin/varnishd
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 00680000-00681000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 7f87148e8000-7f87148fd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 673405                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 7f87148fd000-7f8714afc000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 673405                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Mar 21 18:49:12 prd-varnish-desktop-s01 varnishd[22455]: Child (16721) said 7f8714afc000-7f8714afd000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 673405                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Here is the VCL file.

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
# Importing VMODs
import std;
import cookie;
import header;


backend default {
    .host = "VIRTUAL-SERVER"; #VIP for web servers
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Normalize requests sent via curls -X mode, LWP, echoping etc.
    if (req.url ~ "^http://") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "http://[^/]*","");
    }

    # Normalize host header (remove :80 or :443)
    if (req.http.host ~ ":[0-9]+$") {
        set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, ":[0-9]+$", "");
    }

     if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "/status/serverup")
    {
        error 200 "OK";
        return(error);
    }

    # This url will always return 200 whenever Varnish is running
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "/varnish_ping"){
        error 200 "OK";
    }

    # Handle purging and banning
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        return(lookup);
    }

    if (req.request == "BAN") {
        ban("obj.http.X-Url ~ " + req.url + " && obj.http.X-Host ~ " + req.http.host);
        error 200 "Banned";
    }

    # Allow to serve stale content if backend fails
    set req.grace = 30m;

    # Always cache the following file types for all users
    if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|css|swf|js|less|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|mp3|ogg)$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }           

    # Handle cookies
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.Cookie);
        # Check if RU and RI cookies contain "LOGGEDOUT" string or are not present
        if ((cookie.get("RU") ~ "(^LOGGEDOUT$)|(^$)") && (cookie.get("RI") ~ "(^LOGGEDOUT$)|(^$)")) {
            # Logged out user, clear all cookies
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        } else {
            # Logged in or guest user, keep only useful cookies
            cookie.filter_except("RI,RU,RS,BIGipServerPOOL_APP-DESKTOP-LB,JSESSIONID,_RSID,_rsid,_RREF,_RLVH,_POOLAMDEFAULT,_POOLAMROW,_POOLADDEFAULT,_POOLADROW");
            set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();
        }
    }
}

sub vcl_pass {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        error 502 "PURGE on a passed object";
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 404 "Not in cache";
    }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    # Store URL and Host in obj to allow smart bans
    set beresp.http.X-Url = req.url;
    set beresp.http.X-Host = req.http.host;

    # Handle grace mode
    set beresp.grace = 30m;

    # Don't cache 302 redirects
    if (beresp.status == 302) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:302 REDIRECT";
        return(hit_for_pass);
    }

    # Always cache the following file types for all users
    if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|css|swf|js|less|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|mp3|ogg)$") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }           

    # Handle Set-Cookie
    if (header.get(beresp.http.Set-Cookie, "RI=") || header.get(beresp.http.Set-Cookie, "RU=")) {
        # Keep cookies (RI,RU,RUUID,RS,BIGipServerPOOL_APP-DESKTOP-LB,JSESSIONID,_RSID,_rsid)
    }
    else {
        # Remove Set-Cookie when needed
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }

    # Handle Cache-control headers
    if (    beresp.http.Pragma ~ "no-cache" ||
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache" ||
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private" ) {
            set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private or no-cache";
                        return (hit_for_pass);
        }

    if (    beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
            # Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
            set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO: ttl<=0s or set-cookie or vary:*";
            set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
            return (hit_for_pass);
    }

    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";

    # Don't cache 404 and 5xx answers too long
    if ( (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status >= 500) && beresp.ttl > 300s ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
    }

    # Will avoid going through default vcl_fetch
    return(deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Remove internal headers
    unset resp.http.X-Url;
    unset resp.http.X-Host;

    # Add specific log entries
    # "%t %h %S %{userId}r %{rUuid}r %m '%U%q' &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; %{rnkrPageType}r %{listId}r &quot;%{relListIds}r&quot; %{isMob}r"
    if (resp.http.x-userId) {
        std.log("userId:"+resp.http.x-userId);
    }
    if (resp.http.x-rnkrPageType) {
        std.log("rnkrPageType:"+resp.http.x-rnkrPageType);
    }
    if (resp.http.x-listId) {
        std.log("listId:"+resp.http.x-listId);
    }
    if (resp.http.x-relListIds) {
        std.log("relListIds:"+resp.http.x-relListIds);
    }
    if (resp.http.x-isMob) {
        std.log("isMob:"+resp.http.x-isMob);
    }
        if (resp.http.x-isPersonalized) {
        std.log("isPersonalized:"+resp.http.x-isPersonalized);
    }

    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    }
    else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    if (obj.status == 404){
        set obj.http.MyError = std.fileread("/var/www/status/404.html");
        synthetic obj.http.MyError;
    }

    if (obj.status == 503){
        set obj.http.MyError = std.fileread("/var/www/status/503.html");
        synthetic obj.http.MyError;
    }

    if (obj.status == 200){
        set obj.http.MyError = std.fileread("/var/www/status/serverup.html");
        synthetic obj.http.MyError;
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

Comment: We'll need your VCL file to help diagnose the issue

Comment: Adding the VCL file, thank you so much for the response!

Comment: To help me narrow it down, can you remove the if statement block after "# Handle cookies". I believe your issue is caused by libvmod-cookie and want to confirm.

Comment: Cookie is important in our case because, we need to by pass caching if user logged in. and its product get ~4000 request/sec. Can you explain me what may be the problem in using the cookies, Thank you!